# jQuery each with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

jeMarkers is an array of Google Maps markers.

```
function toggleBounce() {
    var bcounter = 0;
    $(jeMarkers).each(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
                this.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }, bcounter * 100);
        bcounter++;
    });
}
```

If I do the same without the setTimeout function it works but obviously does all the markers at once:

```
function toggleBounce() {
    $.each(jeMarkers, function () {
        if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
            this.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try the setTimeout in the `$.each` instead of `$("element").each()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cache the `this` object inside the function since the context of the setTimeout is not automatically set:

```
function toggleBounce() {
    var bcounter = 0;
    $(jeMarkers).each(function () {
        var that = this; // <- Cache the item
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (that.getAnimation() != null) {
                that.setAnimation(null); // <- Now we can call stuff on the item
            } else {
                that.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }, bcounter * 100);
        bcounter++;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is called a closure (as in: *"JavaScript creates a closure around `var that`"*), and it's one of JavaScript most useful features. More on closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: That's it! I'm so sure I did something similar in all my attempts but I obviously didn't get it right. Thanks a lot!!